# How to cast static variable as a constant and use it to pass to class constructor that expecting final

Tags: flutter, dart

Got an error for following code

```
Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.  
Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'.     
static const MyClass darkerText = MyClass(param);
```

Understood that using `static` in this instance might be inappropriate. Just wanted to look if there is any possible way to do so.

```dart
class MyClass {
  final int total;
  MyClass(total);
}

class Test {
  static int param = 10;
  static const MyClass darkerText = MyClass(param);
}

main() {
  new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the point of `const` and `final`. `const` is for values that are known at compile time, so in your case this is possible, though somewhat pointless, if all your values are compile time constants:

```
class MyClass {
    final int total;
    const MyClass(this.total);
}

class Test {
    static const int param = 10;
    static const MyClass darkerText = MyClass(param);
}

main() {
    new Test();
}
```

What is more normal is to use `final` variables, which can be set during the program's lifecycle but don't change after being set, in which case you would use something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    final int total;
    MyClass(this.total);
}

class Test {
    static int param = 10;
    static final MyClass darkerText = MyClass(param);
}

main() {
    new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code in DartPad 
You need to use `this.total` and remove `const` keyword of `darkerText`

```
class MyClass {
  final int total;
  MyClass(this.total);
}

class Test {
  static int param = 10;
  static MyClass darkerText = MyClass(param);
}

main() {  
  print(Test.darkerText.total);
  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your `MyClass` is a non-const constructor.Make it const:

```
class MyClass {
  final int total;
  const MyClass(this.total);
}

class Test {
  static const int param = 10;
  static const MyClass darkerText = MyClass(param);
}

void main() {
  new Test();
}
```